# External monitor worked but stopped working

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I've been a Linux user for some time now, but cannot seem to tackle this problem.

I've got a 34inch ultrawide Xiaomi monitor at home (this one: https://www.mi.com/global/monitor34/). I've got a 6 year old private laptop and had no problems using the monitor at full resolution 3440x1440. The refresh rate was however limited to 50Hz.

A few months ago I got a new laptop from my company and it worked with the display as well. There were no issues. The laptop has amazing specs, so that shouldn't be an issue.

However, two weeks ago the display stopped working with my bussiness laptop.

There's no error log, no feedback information, absolutely nothing. Both my laptop screen and my monitor go completely black after I connect the monitor to my laptop. After a few seconds, my laptop screen shows up again, but there is no pop-up showing any information.

I can use the monitor with my bussiness laptop, if I set the display resolution to 1280x1024 (of the external monitor). Trying to go up results with a black screen again.

The monitor still works perfectly fine with my laptop, it also works fine with my brothers laptop (~5 years old as well).

I would gladly post any additional info or error logs but there is *nothing* for me to post.

Edit:

Laptop: HP Elitebook 850 G8
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Graphic card: Intel VGA, driver i915

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the Ubuntu version you're using? Also, hardware details (something like "Dell Inspiron 7000") may be helpful.

Comment: If your company will allow it, I'd try booting your business laptop from a live USB with the same version of Ubuntu on it that you're currently using, and see if the monitor works there. If so, that rules out hardware issues on your business laptop, in which case it's possible that a kernel update caused the problem. (Also double-check that the refresh rate for the external monitor is set to 50Hz on your business laptop - if it's not, set it like that and see if that fixes it.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've add the info you asked. Sadly, the refresh rate is already set to 50Hz. Setting it higher than 50Hz doesn't make a difference either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem.

What I needed to do is calculate the necessary parameters using `cvt` and copy the output into `xrandr`. After that selecting my desired resolution was now possible.

```
sudo cvt 3440 1440
```

The output of this command is:

```
# 3440x1440 59.94 Hz (CVT) hysnc: 89.48 kHz; pclk: 419.50 MHz
Modeline "3440x1440_60.00" 419.50 3440 3696 4064 4688 1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Now I pasted everything after "Modeline" into `xrandr`:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00" 419.50 3440 3696 4064 4688 1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Run the next command to see the monitor names.

```
xrandr --listmonitors
```

My external monitor was attached to "HDMI-1". So finally, we run:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 3440x1440_60.00
```

This fixed the issue.